# QTableWidget, centering cellWidgets

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem, qcheckbox

Is there a way to place `QCheckBox` as a cell widget of `QTableWidget` in the center of a cell, not at the left side, without additional `QWidget` and adding the checkbox to it's layout?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `setCellWidget` to add QCheckBox to table:

```
QWidget *checkBoxWidget = new QWidget(); //create QWidget
QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox();   //create QCheckBox
QHBoxLayout *layoutCheckBox = new QHBoxLayout(checkBoxWidget); //create QHBoxLayout 
layoutCheckBox->addWidget(checkBox);     //add QCheckBox to layout
layoutCheckBox->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter); //set Alignment layout
layoutCheckBox->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);

ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(0,0, checkBoxWidget);
```

[image: screenshot]

Also use these line to resize to contents:

```
ui->tableWidget->resizeRowsToContents();
ui->tableWidget->resizeColumnsToContents();
```

> [setCellWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget): Sets the given widget to be displayed in the cell
>   in the given row and column, passing the ownership of the widget to
>   the table.

Reference: https://evileg.com/en/post/79/

Comment: This works.  However, it does not address the OP of aligning the `QCheckBox` in the table cell *without* using an additional `QWidget` as the parent of the `QCheckBox`.  I have not found anything better, though.

Answer (score 2):

I have a simple solution without any additional layout if you want to use `ui->tableWidget->resizeColumnsToContents()`:

Use `checkBox->setStyleSheet( "text-align: center; margin-left:50%; margin-right:50%;" );`

**AFTER this**, call `ui->tableWidget->resizeColumnsToContents()`.

If the column is resized after this (eg. the table gets resized by the layout), you may have to call `ui->tableWidget->resizeColumnsToContents()` again.

It the widget is placed before the resulting column width is known, it retains its (wrong) position. Using resizeColumnsToContents() repositions it.